# How to decrease Slider ball size?

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way to decrease or increase the slider ball size in swiftui?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwiftUI [`Slider`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/slider#) doesn't provide API to customize the ‘thumb’.

[`UISlider`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uislider#) has a [`setThumbImage(_:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uislider/1621336-setthumbimage) that lets you customize the thumb's appearance. You could write your own [`UIViewRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable#) wrapper for `UISlider`. This is what I'd do.

You could also try using [the SwiftUI-Introspect package](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) to get access to the underlying `UISlider` to customize, but I haven't tried it so I don't know how well that works. It might also break in a future version of SwiftUI.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason `.controlSize(_:)` modifier is not working for me.

But I found a decent solution without using `UIViewRepresentable` and Third-party libraries.

Just add UIKit customisation you need inside `.onAppear()` modifier and that's it.

```
Slider(value: $currentValueProgress, in: 0...100, step: 1)
            .accentColor(.white)
            .onAppear {
                let progressCircleConfig = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .small)
                UISlider.appearance()
                    .setThumbImage(UIImage(systemName: "circle.fill",
                                           withConfiguration: progressCircleConfig), for: .normal)
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also add the  .controlSize(_:) modifier.
The options are: .mini, .small and .regular

Comment: On MacOS controlSize works like a charm. There is also a .large size, but it does not actually increase the size of the "thumb". On iOS controlSize does not have an effect.